# Concise way to invoke activity chain, on widget button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have a widget with multiple buttons and want to open an activity that opens another activity according the clicked button

I can do this creating something like

```
 Intent appIntentOpen = new Intent(c, ActivitySeed.class);
                appIntentOpen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                appIntentOpen.putExtra("leafID", 1);
                PendingIntent appPendingIntentOpen1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, REQUEST_CODE, appIntentOpen, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, appPendingIntentOpen1);
```

for each button, where `leafID` is an extra that indicates to `ActivitySeed` what activity must open at the end of its procedure.

I want to avoid to write all the above lines of code for each button since basically if I could get the clicked button id, I could use a method link this

```
public static void openMyActivity(Context c, int leafID) {
        Intent i = new Intent(c, ActivitySeed.class);
        i.putExtra("leafID",leafID);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }
```

To open the `SeedActivity` passing the int ID of leaf.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "want to open an activity that opens another activity according the clicked button" -- why? For example, if your real business objective is that a BACK button press from the second activity would return to the first activity, use `TaskStackBuilder`.

Comment: I don't know well `TaskStackBuilder` anyway in the `SeedActivity` I need that the user perform some actions before the second activity starts

Comment: So basically you have some buttons that share some functionality, and you want to avoid rewriting the code for each ? That sounds a lot like what superclassing the Button class would do to me.

Comment: @personne3000 exactly I want to avoid to write all these codelines, because change only an int parameters between the various button